# Syncing music from device to cloud with Google Play Music

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-music

On my Android device, I've recently downloaded some music. The Google Play Music app recognized the music, and shows it within the app.

However, I am not sure how to sync this new music from my device to the cloud (thus making it available from the Google Play Music browser app on my PC).

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible from your Android device. To sync music with Google Play Music you need the [Google Music Manager](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1229970?hl=en) program on your PC. From there you can sync your music folder with Google and then stream or download it on your device.

There is apparently also the possibility to [do this with the Google play music extension for chrome](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/4627259)